# Is there a way to execute a subquery on a prepared statement result?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, statements

I'm trying to find the statement results which have a specific userid column
Here's the code:

```
$interazionequerystmt_string = "
    SELECT USERID 
    FROM like_calendario_condivisioni 
    WHERE TIPO LIKE ? AND COMUNE LIKE ? AND VIA LIKE ? AND CIVICO LIKE ?";
$interazionequerystmt = $con->prepare($interazionequerystmt_string);
$tipo = "LIKE";
$interazionequerystmt->bind_param("ssss", $tipo, $comune, $via, $civico);
$interazionequerystmt->execute();
$likesquery = $interazionequerystmt->get_result();
```

```
$ennesimaquery = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT * FROM ($likesquery) 
    WHERE USERID LIKE '$sessionuserid'");
```

Comment: Why not just add a condition on `userid` to the original query?

Comment: No.  But since your first query is only returning the USERID field, what would that gain you?  Do you just want to know if the userid is present in that list?

Comment: Do you really need to use `LIKE` rather than `=` for all those conditions? `LIKE` is for matching patterns containing `%` and `_` wildcards.

Comment: The first query returns a list of user ids, i want to select a specific one

Comment: So put the result of the first query in an array, then search for the specific user ID in that array.

Comment: You could do this kind of thing with an ORM library.

Comment: Short answer: No, you cannot query a result. Long answer: You need to step back and re-examine what you're trying to do here. Because, unless there's a bunch of code missing between those two snippets that you've posted, you're doing something pretty strange.